# Using wildcard with Generic method

Tags: java, functional-programming

Would like to get some advise on it

My class structure is like this

```
public abstract class Base {}
public class Derived1 extends Base {}
public class Derived2 extends Base {}

public class ServiceClass {
    public String method1(Derived1 derived1) {
        return "derived1";
    }
    public String method2(Derived2 derived2) {
        return "derived2";
    }
}
```

In my main code (MainProg),I am trying to use the same function to refer to the 2 methods in service class and seeing the compilation error as put in the comment

```
public class MainProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceClass serviceClass = new ServiceClass();

        //Incompatible types: Base is not convertible to Derived1
        Function<? extends Base,String> function1 = serviceClass::method1; 

        //Incompatible types: Object is not convertible to Derived1            
        Function<?,String> function2 = serviceClass::method1;
            
        //Incompatible types: Base is not convertible to Derived2
        Function<? super Base,String> function3 = serviceClass::method2;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to declare my function object so that same function object can be used to refer to methods taking different type of arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using an intermediary variable:

```
    Function<Derived1, String> function1 = serviceClass::method1;
    Function<Derived2, String> function2 = serviceClass::method2;        
    Function<? extends Base, String> function = condition ? function1 : function2;
```

That said, you won't be able to invoke `function`, because you don't know whether to pass a `Derived1` or a `Derived2`, or as the compiler puts it:

```
    function.apply(new Derived2()); 
    // error: The method apply(capture#1-of ? extends Base) in the type Function<capture#1-of ? extends Base,String> is not applicable for the arguments (Derived2)
```

You could, however, use generics to abstract over the argument type:

```
<T extends Base> invokeSafely(Function<T, String> function, T argument) {
    function.apply(argument);
}
```

which would allow you to write

```
invokeSafely(serviceClass::method1, new Derived1());
invokeSafely(serviceClass::method2, new Derived2());
```

but not

```
invokeSafely(function, new Derived1()); // same error as before
```

Comment: "That said, you won't be able to invoke function" You can invoke it, but only with null.

Comment: @Michael: True, but that's not usually useful, so I glossed over it.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Incompatible types: Base is not convertible to Derived1
Function<? extends Base,String> function1 = serviceClass::method1;
```

It's some weird quirk of type inference that I don't fully understand. It's inferring `Function<Base,String>` from the left-hand side and trying to apply it to the right-hand-side.

You can fix it like this. The cast is safe:

```
Function<? extends Base,String> function1 = (Function<Derived1, String>) serviceClass::method1;
```

or this:

```
Function<Derived1, String> tmp = serviceClass::method1;
Function<? extends Base,String> function1 = tmp;
```

It's worth noting that you can never invoke this function (except with `null`), since you have thrown away the knowledge of what type of argument it expects. `? extends Base` is *something* that extends Base (i.e. Derived1 or Derived2) but we don't know which.

```
//Incompatible types: Object is not convertible to Derived1            
Function<?,String> function2 = serviceClass::method1;
```

Same issue as the first one, except it's inferring Object instead of Base.

```
//Incompatible types: Base is not convertible to Derived2
Function<? super Base,String> function3 = serviceClass::method2;
```

Derived1 or Derived2 are not **super**classes of Base. They are subclasses. Only Object is a superclass of Base. `method2` does not expect `Object`.